# Which of these sentences is correct: "Our topic for today is games." or "Our topic for today is about games."?

Tags: prepositions, subject-complement

Which one is correct?

> - Our topic for today is games.
> - Our topic for today is about games.

Comment: But, I would just say *Game is our topic today*.

Comment: So, *Our topic for today is games* is correct?

Comment: For your question, yes, it's correct. But it doesn't sound right for me, probably because you pair *is*, which is singular, with *games*, which is plural.

Comment: The subject is singular so I used *IS* :)

Comment: Definitely the first one. If you write it like this, it will be much clearer: Our topic, for today, is, "Games." It's because you had used the word topic and so the reader is expecting you to name the topic ("Games"), and not only describe what the topic will be ("about games").

Comment: @user178049 - "Game is our topic today" isn't correct.  *Game* is a countable noun, so it would have to be *a game*, *the game*, or *games*.  And Zakiya is right; *topic* is a singular noun, so "our topic **is**" is correct.

Comment: *Our topic  today is "games"* OR *Today's topic is "games"*

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the first one.

If you write it like this, it will be much clearer:

> Our topic, for today, is, "Games."

It's because you had used the word "topic" and so the reader is expecting you to not only to describe the topic ("about games"), but to actually name the topic ("Games").

Meanwhile, if you had written:

> Our discussion, for today, is about games.

Then, I would definitely see an argument for including "about."

Answer (score 1):

Your topic **is** something, because [*topic* means "a subject of conversation or discussion"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/topic).  Your discussion, lesson, book, etc. is **about** something because that is what its topic is.  As you can see in Google Ngrams, [in books, "topic is the" is far more common than "topic is about the".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=topic%20is%20the%2Ctopic%20is%20about%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctopic%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctopic%20is%20about%20the%3B%2Cc0)